# filtering out onClick from a mapped array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to figure out how to filter out a mapped array and making the rest of the results disappear in the same component. I've done the same with React Router as I can route the result to a different page but I am wondering if there is a way to do the same on the same component? I have a Directory component (below) that is mapping through an array to display results of items on the page.

I would like to click on one of the  elements and remove the rest. I tried to incorporate a filter method in the same component but drawing blanks on how I should implement it. Let me know what you think!

```
import React from 'react'
import { Card, CardImg} from 'reactstrap'

function Presentational({example, onClick}){
    return(
        <Card onClick={()=> onClick(example.name) }>
            <CardImg src={example.image}/>
        </Card>
    )
}

function Directory(props){

    const examples = props.propExample.map(example=>{
        return (
            <div>
                <Presentational example={example} onClick={props.onClick} />
            </div>
        )
    })

    return(
        <div>
            {examples}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Directory;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use useState hook for selection

We store clicked elements inside the state variable selected. using useState hook.
When the user clicks on the element react component will remember which element he clicked and will render an array from 1 clicked element `[selected]`.

In order to cleanup selection, just call `setSelected()`

It is the same logic as you want.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { Card, CardImg} from 'reactstrap'

function Presentational({example, onClick}){
    return(
        <Card onClick={()=> onClick(example.name) }>
            <CardImg src={example.image}/>
        </Card>
    )
}

function Directory(props){
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState()
    const examples = (selected ? [selected] : props.propExample).map(example=>{
        return (
            <div>
                <Presentational example={example} onClick={(name) => {
                     props.onClick(name)
                     setSelected(example)
                  }}
                />
            </div>
        )
    })

    return(
        <div>
            {examples}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Directory;
```

if you want to do it with a filter clause it will look almost the same, but with the extra operations

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { Card, CardImg} from 'reactstrap'

function Presentational({example, onClick}){
    return(
        <Card onClick={()=> onClick(example.name) }>
            <CardImg src={example.image}/>
        </Card>
    )
}

function Directory(props){
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState()
    const examples = props.propExample.filter(it => typeof selected === 'undefined' || it.name === selected).map(example=>{
        return (
            <div>
                <Presentational example={example} onClick={(name) => {
                     props.onClick(name)
                     setSelected(name)
                  }}
                />
            </div>
        )
    })

    return(
        <div>
            {examples}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Directory;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I tried to use what you wrote but once I clicked on a Card, everything went away.. I wonder if i am doing something wrong still?

Comment: @JasonTodd my bad, should be setSelected(example). Fixed

Comment: Thank you! That worked! May I ask, since I'm not familiar with useState(), would implementing the filter array method be complicating? I am assuming so because since I am already mapping the array of objects I have from the state in my Main component file..sorry  I am new so trying to grasp this...

Comment: There is no need filtering array, as it will not bring any performance benefits. After you click - you suppose to store where did you click. We store clicked element with useState hook. Otherwise, we will not be able to know what element we suppose to show. In order to clean up you may call setSelected() and ti will show all elements again.

Comment: @JasonTodd I have updated the answer with a filter option.

Comment: Thanks @rockTheWorld . That makes a lot of sense and again, Thank you so much for providing both solutions. I'll need to study these to make sure. Quite positive I'll run into this issue in the future.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225302/discussion-between-jason-todd-and-rocktheworld).